# Mypy check with dataclass field and alias

Tags: python, mypy, python-dataclasses

I'm struggling with mypy and dataclasses and especially with the `field` function.

Here is an example

```
from dataclasses import field, dataclass

@dataclass
class C:
    some_int: int
    some_str: str = field(metadata={"doc": "foo"})
    another_int: int

c = C(42, "bla", 43)
```

So far, so good. Mypy and python are happy

However, if I want to make a small helper around `field` to easily write my doc

```
def doc(documentation: str):
    return field(metadata={"doc": documentation})
```

Now I write my class like this:

```
@dataclass
class C:
    some_int: int
    some_str: str = doc("foo")
    another_int: int
```

And mypy throws

```
error: Attributes without a default cannot follow attributes with one
```

Both are equivalent, but it seems mypy have a special case around `field` (if I understand correctly)

https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/v0.790/mypy/plugins/dataclasses.py#L359

So, my question is: is there a workaround to be able to write alias an for `field`?

Should I raise a bug on mypy?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Pycharm's inspection has the same issue too.

Comment: What if you annotate the `doc()` function to return a `dataclasses.Field`?

Comment: @alkasm I tried, no luck


```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Field[Any]", variable has type "str")

error: Attributes without a default cannot follow attributes with one
```

Comment: Ah yeah I see the special casing you linked. I imagine then that this is by design. Mypy constructs the `_fullname` attribute for the function call in its stack and there doesn't seem to be an easy/built-in way to inject the `"dataclasses.field"` name anywhere for you to re-use.